# why push down automata need a initial stack symbol?

Tags: automata-theory

while defining a transition of CFG or type-2 grammer with PDA we need initial stack-symbol mostly denoted by Zo.
my doubt is why we need it because finally we are going to empty the stack  at all....??

Answer (score 2):

Pushdown automata need the initial stack symbol because each move is determined by the current input symbol and the one at the top of the stack. This leads to the reality that no move is possible if the stack is empty.

And yes the stack can be reduced to only the stack symbol. Consider...

`L={ (a^n)(b^n) : n >= 0 }`

I could push down a `0` for each `a` I read, which - btw - the first of which will be (q0, a, z), and then when I read my first `b` I pop `0`s and push nothing back. I know that I'm done and the language is accepted when there's no input consumed and the stack symbol is atop the stack.

Notice in the transition function above the first move is determined by the first input and the stack symbol. Can you see how without it you'd never be able to start?

Comment: What will happen if i am in state `q0` and stack has `z` as initial state. and i remove `z` from the the stack and go to `q1`, I took `q1` as accepting state.  as you said, if i give more input to `q1` it will not be accepted bcoz now the stack is empty.! but will `q1` be accepted or it will be unaccepted .?